# Git:does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, push

I am trying to make repository to the local server.

In server side I have done the below steps:

```
mkdir -p /root/project-1.git
cd /root/project-1.git
git init --bare
```

So at server side I have made the git repository.

Now at client side I have done following things:

```
mkdir -p /root/remote
cd /root/remote
git init
```

Made a simple hello file.

```
git add .
git commit -m "message" -a
git remote add origin ssh://git@10.206.1.34/root/project-1.git
```

Now when I am pushing this changes to server by using the following command it gives me following error:

```
git push origin master
git@10.206.1.34's password:
fatal: '/root/project-1.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Comment: does the git user on server have access to `/root/project-1.git`? did you use that user when creating the repo?

Comment: Yes git user has permission to access  /root/project-1.git

Comment: What if you clone the project with `git clone git@10.206.1.34:/root/project-1.git` ?

Comment: same error:fatal: '/root/project-1.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: And with `git clone root@10.206.1.34:/root/project-1.git`?

Comment: yes using "git clone root@10.206.1.34:/root/project-1.git"  it is working.Thanks.But why it is not working with git user?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission problem. Since the directory `/root/project-1.git` belongs to the root user on the server (which IMHO is a bad idea), you have to clone the project with the root user: `git clone root@10.206.1.34:/root/project-1.git`.

An alternative is to change the owner of the bare directory, on the server, run

```
chown -R git:git /root/project-1.git
```

so that you can clone it with the git user (it this user does not exist on the server you will have to create it). You should reconsider having your repositories inside the root home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .git extension in the server side when you create the repository:

```
mkdir -p /root/project-1
cd /root/project-1
git init --bare
```

The commands on the client side should remain the same (with the .git extension)